# Changing hostname on boot on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, hostname

I would like to configure a Debian Stretch machine so that it sets its hostname on boot based on the machine's serial number. This is due to the fact that the OS on the machine I'm configuring will be copied on several other machines, and they must be able to automatically set up their (unique) hostname on boot.

I created a systemd service to do that. The service calls a script which checks the machine's serial number, determines the correct hostname for that machine, and then edits the two files `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` accordingly. I set up the service in order to run after the filesystems are ready and **before** networking is configured. Here it is:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target
Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/set-hostname.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

When the machine boots I can see that the two files have been edited correctly. However, the command line prompt still shows the old hostname (which was in `/etc/hostname` before rebooting) and if I run the command `hostnamectl` I get the following information:

```
Static hostname: new_correct_hostname
Transient hostname: old_hostname
```

where `new_correct_hostname` is the one generated by my script and written in `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` at boot, while `old_hostname` is the one which was in those file *before* rebooting.

Why doesn't the transient hostname correctly update when the network goes up? Is there any other service which sets it up before my script changes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man` page for hostnamectl the transient hostname is read from network configuration and is not used if static hostname is configured and valid.

This suggests there might be some cached network configuration with previous hostname that sets your transient hostname to the old one. Further investigation there will depend on the method and service you use to connect to network.

Alternatively, if you want to be absolutely sure your runtime hostname is set correctly, you can let the Linux kernel know either by command `/bin/hostname` provided by `hostname` package or by manually inserting new name into `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`, eg.:

```
echo myhost > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

Any newly opened login shell will show the updated hostname after this is executed.